# Moving object to location of touch

Tags: objective-c, swift, sprite-kit

How can I move the 'player' position to be where the user touches the screen? I want them to be able to move it constantly by tapping different places. This is what I have so far but it's not working:

class GameScene: SKScene {

```
let player = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Spaceship")

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    // 2
    backgroundColor = SKColor.whiteColor()
    // 3
    player.position = CGPoint(x: size.width/2, y: size.height/2)

    // 4
    addChild(player)




}

override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    /* Called when a touch begins */

    for touch: AnyObject in touches {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

        let player = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"Spaceship")
        player.position = location




    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the line `let player = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"Spaceship")` in `touchesBegan` you are creating a new instance of the spaceship node. 
This node is not in the scene and setting the position of the new node does not change the position of the existing player node.

Just try resetting the position of you player node instead.

Try

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

    let touch = touches.anyObject() as UITouch?
    if let location = touch?.locationInNode(self)
    {
        player.position = location
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I knew it would be something silly :)